# C programming: How to use mmap(2) to read file parallel by multiple threads?

Tags: c, multithreading, memory-management, mmap, virtual-memory

I am trying to write multi-threaded code to read file in fixed chunks using [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) and counts the words. Each thread works on a separate portion of the file, making faster processing of the file.  I am able to read the file using [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) single threaded. When the number of threads is more than one, it fails with a segmentation fault.

```
for( unsigned long cur_pag_num = 0; cur_pag_num < total_blocks; cur_pag_num++ ) {
    mmdata = mmap(
        NULL, PAGE_SIZE, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, (fileOffset + (cur_pag_num * PAGE_SIZE))
    );

    if (mmdata == MAP_FAILED) printf(" mmap error ");

    unsigned  long wc = getWordCount( mmdata );
    parserParam->wordCount +=wc;
    munmap( mmdata, PAGE_SIZE );
}

unsigned long getWordCount(char *page){
     unsigned long wordCount=0;
     for(long i = 0 ; page[i] ;i++ ){
        if(page[i]==' ' || page[i]=='\n')
            wordCount++;
     }
     return wordCount;
}
```

I have figured out that code fails inside `getWordCount(mmdata)`.  What am I doing wrong here?

Note: size of file is more than the size of main memory. So reading in fixed size chunks (`PAGE_SIZE`).

Comment: Your code doesn't abort when `mmap` fails. You need to add a `break` or `return` in your `if( mmdata == MAP_FAILED )` branch. You should also check `errno` to determine the exact type of error.

Comment: You might want to use `size_t` instead of `unsigned long` to be more portable.

Comment: The problem is probably in `getWordCount()`, not the code here. How does it know how big the chunk is, when you just pass a pointer to it?

Comment: @Barmar i have added code for your reference.

Comment: `getWordCount` expects `page` to be a null-terminated satring. `mmap()` doesn't add a null terminator, so you're accessing outside the page.

Comment: @Dai .thanks for the suggestion . I have added return statement to break the flow. I have also added print statement to trace the `errno`. It is failing with  error `EINVAL`. I still don't know why ?

Comment: @Barmar Then why code works well with single thread ? and if that is case, what is work around?

Comment: I don't know why it's working in a single thread. I don't even see any thread-related code in the question. I posted an answer showing how to do it correctly.

Comment: You're probably messing up the offset value to mmap. It has to be a multiple of PAGE_SIZE. By the way, mmap in a loop for tiny 4K blocks is kind of inefficient. Unless the file is ginormous just mmap the entire thing and pass chunks of it to your threads.

Comment: @ZanLynx I am adding `fileOffset` to make sure each thread starts reading at different portion of file for thread id 0,`fileOffset` will be `0`,  for thread id 1  `fileOffset` will be `1 * (fileSize/threadCount)` and so on . value for `PAGE_SIZE` is 64KB.

Comment: @code_sniper: But the separate mmaps in the threads is just slow and bad planning. mmap or munmap calls force the kernel to lock *all* your threads while it updates the memory map. Because all your threads share the same memory map.

Comment: @code_sniper `threadNumber * filesize/threadCount` isn't likely to be a multiple of `PAGE_SIZE`. That's probably why you're getting `EINVAL`.

Comment: @ZanLynx why `map` is shared across the thread? Each thread calls map method with different `fd`, as each thread calls `open()`. Also, can you explain how `mmap` behave in the threaded environment?

Comment: Here is an LWN article that mentions the problem in passing: https://lwn.net/Articles/568076/

Answer (score 0):

`getWordCount` is accessing outside the mapped page, because the loop stops when it finds a null byte. But `mmap()` doesn't add a null byte after the mapped page. You need to pass the size of the mapped page to the function. It should stop when it reaches either that index or a null byte (if the file isn't long enough to fill the page, the rest of the page will be zeros).

```
for( unsigned long cur_pag_num = 0; cur_pag_num < total_blocks; cur_pag_num++ ) {
    mmdata = mmap(
        NULL, PAGE_SIZE, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, (fileOffset + (cur_pag_num * PAGE_SIZE))
    );

    if (mmdata == MAP_FAILED) printf(" mmap error ");

    unsigned  long wc = getWordCount( mmdata, PAGE_SIZE );
    parserParam->wordCount +=wc;
    munmap( mmdata, PAGE_SIZE );
}

unsigned long getWordCount(char *page, size){
     unsigned long wordCount=0;
     for(long i = 0 ; i < size && page[i] ;i++ ){
        if(page[i]==' ' || page[i]=='\n')
            wordCount++;
     }
     return wordCount;
}
```

BTW, there's another problem with your approach: a word that spans page boundaries will be counted twice.

Comment: I had made modification as you said, it is still failing. As suggested by @Dai i have added return statement and print the `errno`. Code is failing with `EINVAL` error. I don't know why though.   I am aware of situation of words being counted twice. Also, i have also posted part of code which is being called by thread method. If you want I can share rest of the code.

Comment: In what way is it failing?

Comment: I have made following modification to code `if (mmdata == MAP_FAILED){ printf(" mmap error %d", errno); return -1;}`

Comment: Why not use `perror()` so you see the error message instead of numeric `errno`?

Comment: Check the man page to see all the possible reasons to get `EINVAL` from `mmap()`. I'm not sure why it only happens when you use threads, maybe you're not passing parameters to the threads properly.